How can I make truly round circles?
I am drawing a compass circle on a windows form app.  I have two monitors and the resulting circles are not round.  On monitor A they are tall ellipses, and on monitor B they are wide ellipses.  I also note that pictures do the same thing when moved from monitor to monitor.
At first I thought it was due to different screen size ratios, but that is not it.  It actually seems that the pixels are not square, and are a different geometry for each monitor. Thus mon A has tall narrow pixels and mon B has the opposite.  Or maybe it is that the pixels are closer together, either horizontally or vertically depending on monitor.
I've searched for an answer but cannot find any definitive answer as to how to solve this.  Is there a way for a form app to specify, that for a specified form (or for the whole app) that the System.Drawing.Graphics ouputs are adjusted to match the screen?
Thanks, Russ
I did try to adjust the drawing by trial using a ratio of height/width, and applying it to my bounding rectangles.  I found that a ratio of 1.15:1 works for monitor A.  But there are many parts to my graphics and they all need to be auto adjusted.  Otherwise my code gets very complicated.

Usually, a pixel is square and if it is not the case for your monitors, there would be something unusual. There are some APIs to obtain the monitors' physical information such as DisplayInformation but I am doubtful that it is reliably possibe to get the correct information in such case.
